# Read command from .txt file and run it in batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make batch file read from a .txt and have the output be entered as a command. I have written this code, but it won't work when the command has a spaces in it.

```
@echo off

:READ
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%c in (C:\file.txt) do (set command=%%c)
%command%

goto READ
```

What do I do to make it work?

Comment: seems to work fine for me. Give example line and output. You may want to work with `echo on` to see, what's happening.

Comment: Update your question with examples from your text file that are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you want to do:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (C:\file.txt) do %%c
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this if you need to have the command variable to do other stuff (beside executing) with it. If this is not the case @Henrik's answer would suffice:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:READ
for /f "tokens=* usebackq delims=" %%c in ("C:\file.txt") do (
set "command=%%c"
!command!
)
pause
```